# JQuery building variable with variable

Tags: jquery, variables, eval

i've already look around but impossible to make it work

I have those variable value

```
var price208 = '23432';
var price308 = '123';
var model = '';
```

After some button click interaction on my page i define my "model" var to be either 208 or 308 (each of my button have unique ID like button208 or button308, so i extract 'model' from ID name with simple substring)

Right after button click i want to do an alert like this

```
alert(price+model)
```

In fact i want to compose my variable in alert with one of my variable (model)

i've tryed price[model] but of course 'price' is not defined.

Anybody have a quick solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variable names dynamically like that.. instead you can use create those dynamic items as object properties and access them via the property key.

```
var obj = {
    price208: '23432',
    price308: '123'
}

var model = '208';

obj['price' + model]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L7ta3xm3/)

On a side note, if those variables are in the global scope they will be available as the properties of `window` object, so you can use them.

```
var price208 = '23432';
var price308 = '123';
var model = '208';

alert(window['price' + model])
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4dbmdrLr/)